# Accessing Files on Sharepoint

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint-2013

I try to access an Excel file stored in a Sharepoint folder.
I used the file properties to retrieve the full path:
https://group.sharepoint.com/sites/...
The path works fine in Excel. it works also fine when I paste it in Internet Explorer. I can access either the folder content or the file without having to provide any password.

Pbm: when I try to use the os.chdir method, I got the following message:
[WinError 224] Access Denied. Before opening files in this location,
you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list,
browse to the web site, and select the option to login automatically.

Opening the file in this location is ok.
I added the web site to the list of trusted sites. ok.
I apparently already log in automatically.
I tried with and without the "https:".
None of those attempts gave any result. I keep having this WinError 224 message.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to get rid of this message? I ran out of ideas and found nothing on the web...

Comment: Is is possible to find the drive on a local network share drive instead? That may be easier if it is an option.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, https://github.com/JonathanHolvey/sharepy might be helpful I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It will happen if using sharepoint-online.

you have to install one-drive and use one time sync in sharepoint, the cloud files will store in your local pc, access them as your local files.

one drive will keep the file up-to-date